# Why does my code keep refreshing in a refresh rate that is in powers of 2 (also how can I effectively limit frame rate)

Tags: python, python-3.x, game-engine

So, this definitely isn't the right coding language to do this in, but for fun I'm trying to write a python based 2D game-engine. Right now I'm working on delta time and frame rate limiting. I've gotten the delta time down easy but am getting stuck on the FPS limiting. I think my issue might be stimming from the fact that my code seems to be running naturally in refresh rates in powers of 2. usually close to 64 or 32.

Here is a VERY stripped down example of the problem. Though stripped down, all this code is the same that shows up in my game engine (save for the print commands)

```
import time

previousTime = time.time()
time.sleep(0.00001)
dT = 0

#for loop in place of the normal while loop

for x in range(3):

#Frame Number

  print(x)

#Determine Current Frame Time

  now = time.time()

#Determine Delta Time

  dT = now - previousTime

#Print All Values for Debug

  print('now ' + str(now))
  print('p time ' + str(previousTime))
  print('dT ' + str(dT))

#Save Previous Time

  previousTime = now

#Find Difference Between Time it Took the Previous Frame and the Target Time (.016 seconds is the time a frame should take at 60fps)

  frameTimingDif = 0.016 - dT

#Print more values for debug

  print('time dif ' + str(frameTimingDif))
  #Howdy partner, love ya for reading all this ;)
  print('FPS ' + str(1/dT))

#attempt to sleep for the remaining time to get down to 60fps (if it fails, usually because of framingTimingDif being a negative number)

  try:
    time.sleep(frameTimingDif)
  except:
    print('woops')
```

Here is the result:

```
0
now 1634974666.2838764
p time 1634974666.2682076
dT 0.015668869018554688
time dif 0.00033113098144531283
FPS 63.820815581253804
1
now 1634974666.2995417
p time 1634974666.2838764
dT 0.015665292739868164
time dif 0.00033470726013183627
FPS 63.83538543489841
2
now 1634974666.3151739
p time 1634974666.2995417
dT 0.015632152557373047
time dif 0.00036784744262695346
FPS 63.97071652990879
[Finished in 156ms]
```

**SOOO** long story, not so short, I'm wondering why my python is running in refresh rates of powers of 2 and if there is a way to do frame limiting better.

Big thanks in advance for any answers, friends.

p.s. If you put a `time.sleep(0.000001)` at the begining of the loop then you get an example of the 32 fps return.

```
0
now 1634976028.433253
p time 1634976028.4020138
dT 0.03123927116394043
time dif -0.01523927116394043
FPS 32.01099010127684
woops
1
now 1634976028.4489527
p time 1634976028.433253
dT 0.01569962501525879
time dif 0.00030037498474121127
FPS 63.6957888502483
2
now 1634976028.4801967
p time 1634976028.4489527
dT 0.03124403953552246
time dif -0.01524403953552246
FPS 32.006104680000306
woops
[Finished in 156ms]
```